# Which div is active with jQuery Content Panel Switcher?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery Content Panel Switcher https://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/, but would like to use some css on the item that is active to show the user what has been selected, but from looking at the demo, I can't see any difference in the selected item and others.

Is there a way to do this?

Basically something like if an id is selected, make that link red or bold

In their example, something that makes the tab that is selected look different.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a selector for the link or the panel?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to get the ID of A item just clicked and style it using jQuery.

Something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav_buttons a').click(function(event){
        $('.nav_buttons a').css({ 'background-color' : '' }); //clear past selections
        $(this).css({ 'background-color' : 'red' }); //set new selection
    });    
  });
```

Style and code it according to your need.

Here's the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/n4pPy/1/

Comment: Could this be expanded to change the css when the panel is set to a class of show also? This works great once you click, but I want it to reflect that status onload as well.

Comment: Does that mean when you land on the page..you want to highlight Home item?